# Reading a tabulated website into a list

Tags: python, web, web-crawler

I am trying to automate a data gathering process from this website: https://sitem.herts.ac.uk/aeru/ppdb/en/Reports/399.htm

The website is set up in a tabular format and so I imagine that it must be relatively simple to parse the data into a set of lists but I am not sure where to start.

So, for example in the webpage linked above a part of the data is fomatted as follows:

[image]

I know how to read the source code out using python:

```
    import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen("https://sitem.herts.ac.uk/aeru/ppdb/en/Reports/399.htm").read(20000) # read only 20 000 chars
data = data.split("\n") # then split it into lines

for line in data:
    print line
```

But I don't know how to actually read the text itself, ideally in a way that preserves the formatting so I can identify each table and then see, for example, what the GUS leaching potential is.

It would be very helpful to be directed to some of the methods that I could use, because I have not got any idea where to start!

Comment: I would recommend you to use beautiful soup, you can take a look at this tutorial http://web.stanford.edu/~zlotnick/TextAsData/Web_Scraping_with_Beautiful_Soup.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take a look. Are there any others you would recommend?